# Select previous row mysql?

Tags: mysql

If I have a mysql table which had primary ids and another field called gameScore can I do something along the lines of...

```
SELECT gameScore FROM table1 WHERE id = 100 ORDER BY gameScore ASC
```

This will get the gameScore for the id 100, but what I would like to do is have mysql order the table by gameScore and then select the previous row to where the id = 100, if that makes sense thanks...

Comment: What if current and previous `gameScore` are equal?

Comment: Then it should select the next highest.

Answer (score 0):

looks funny - but maybe this is what you're after.

```
select max( gameScore )
from table1
where id = 100
and gameScore < ( select max( gameScore ) from table1 where id = 100 )
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the Lag feature mentioned on this site
http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

Comment: not natively, but the link seems to show how to implement this feature

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a union instead of the AND (besides, you need to add LIMIT 1 so you do not get ALL rows under 100)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the second lowest score, right? Like Craig mentioned, limit sounds like the right way to go:

```
SELECT 
  gameScore 
FROM 
  table1 
WHERE 
  id = 100 
ORDER BY 
  gameScore ASC 
limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(gameScore) gameScore FROM table1
      WHERE id = 100 AND gameScore < 50 ORDER BY gameScore
  ) t2
    On t1.id = t2.id AND t1.gameScore = t2.gameScore
```

To find previous record we need to select exact current record, in example it is a record with `id` = 100 and `gameScore` = 50.