# How to get previous or next row in a given row in mysql using lead or lag?

Tags: mysql, sql, lag, lead

I've been reading on lead and lag functions but I still don't get it. My sql syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT description, lag(description) over (ORDER BY transid ASC) 
  FROM transaction 
 WHERE transid = 20;
```

It's not returning the desired data. I have a table where transid is the primary key in int, and a column called description. I think the syntax is wrong because I want to return the whole row (all the column data) and I think this just returns one column of the previous row. How do I do that? Anybody?

Return an entire previous/next row.

Comment: can you share the input and desired output?

Comment: I have a table, transid is the primary key and the other columns are for example refpage, refline, description, accountcode, codetype. I enter a value of transid that is equal to 10 and I want to get the values of the row before 10, so that's 9, and all the columns that 9 has. Or for the next row I'll get the column values of 11. How do I get the data? The output is all the columns of a previous row or next row. The input is 10.

Comment: I am using mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next/previous record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894092/select-previous-row-mysql

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Perhaps the WHERE clause has already removed the rows you want.

Comment: it says mysql 8.0 at my app menu..

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a subquery with `LEAD` to restrict to the desired previous record:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LEAD(transid) OVER (ORDER BY transid) transid_lead
    FROM transaction
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE transid_lead = 20;
```

Comment: The query doesn't return any values.. just the column names.. maybe there's something wrong with mysql and lag/lead functions..

Comment: What value does the subquery return?

Comment: just a null value.

Comment: Then there is no "previous" value for `transid = 20`, or there is no `transid = 20` record to begin with.

Comment: OK, is there any record where `transid` is less than 20?  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction WHERE transid < 20`

Comment: the value is 14 for count

Comment: `WHERE` clause will remove all rows but one so there is no prev or next row.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for cracking this problem, +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For previous row you can simply do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction
WHERE transid < 20 
ORDER BY transid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

For next row you reverse the conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction
WHERE transid > 20 
ORDER BY transid ASC
LIMIT 1
```